# Iphone Phonegap in-app purchase not working

Tags: iphone, cordova, in-app-purchase

I have a phonegap project using which i have submitted my application at iPhone app store.

I m using cordova-2.2.0.js.  Now I want to implement in-app purchase plugin to provide in-app purchase in my application.

I am trying to do it by adding in-app plugin from the link below:

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager
```

I then added InAppPurchase plugin to cordova.plist file.

When I write below mentioned code

(a) in my javascript, the control goes to InAppPurchaseManager.js plugin and code

(b) is executed.

(a)

```
   window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.requestProductData(
         "org.xxx.abcd.pqr", 
         function(productId, title, description, price) {
             alert("data retrieved");
             //window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.makePurchase(productId, 1);
         },
         function(id) {
             alert("Invalid product id: " + id);
         }
     );
```

(b)

```
    InAppPurchaseManager.prototype.requestProductData = function(productId, successCallback, failCallback) {

    var key = 'f' + this.callbackIdx++;
    window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.callbackMap[key] = {
        success: function(productId, title, description, price ) {
        if (productId == '__DONE') {
            delete window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.callbackMap[key]
            return;
        }
        successCallback(productId, title, description, price);
     },
         fail: failCallback
    }
        alert("product id: " + productId + "key: " + key);
        var callback = 'window.plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.callbackMap.' + key;
        cordova.exec('InAppPurchaseManager.requestProductData', productId, callback + '  .success', callback + '.fail');    

  }
```

In code (b), everything works fine, till the line below:

```
cordova.exec('InAppPurchaseManager.requestProductData', productId, callback + '.success', callback + '.fail');
```

The question is: Why the app get stop at the above mentioned line. Also the alert box is displayed in code (b) which belongs to `InAppPurchaseManager.js`.

I have added an in-app item at itunesconnect and it is in "ready to submit" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

In phonegap 1.8.1, we have to remove the prefix cdvjk_ from cdvjk_JSONRepresentation and all other variables from InAppPurchaseManager.m file.

I was able to perform in-app successfully..

Answer (score 0):

Got it working somehow..

There was some problem in sandboxing the application.  I also moved to Xcode 4.3 from 4.2.

Now I am able to fetch product details and get the log as below:
- Getting product data..
- Got iap product response..
- Sending js for "abc.pqr.xyz.productid" (product id)

followed by the exception:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI cdvjk_JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9156f40'

Googled it but didn't find much.. I am using cordova-1.8.1.

Any solutions??

Comment: Does the solution for ["Objective-C errors after getting the IAP product response"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870457/objective-c-errors-after-getting-the-iap-product-response) work for you?