# Objective-C errors after getting the IAP product response

Tags: objective-c, cordova

This code is from the Phonegap Code: IAP Plugin.  The error happens on the line of the code right after the "sent js".  All the elements sent to the function are non-nil except for the last one 'nil'.  I even logged them out to make sure they were sent.  This code is right out of the plugin (https://github.com/usmart/InAppPurchaseManager-EXAMPLE) and has not been modified except for the logging.  In the debugger i saw that none of the objects were nil, so i don't understand why the error is happening.

Here is the error:

> [__NSArrayI JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0xdc542d0
>       2013-02-13 23:26:17.209 GoblinSlots[4519:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSArrayI JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0xdc542d0'

here is the code:

```
      - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:   (SKProductsResponse *)response
      {
        NSLog(@"got iap product response");
        for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
            NSLog(@"sending js for %@", product.productIdentifier);
            NSLog(@"  title %@", product.localizedTitle );
            NSLog(@"  desc%@ - %@", product.localizedDescription, product.localizedPrice );


NSArray *callbackArgs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 NILABLE(product.productIdentifier),
                                 NILABLE(product.localizedTitle),
                                 NILABLE(product.localizedDescription),
                                 NILABLE(product.localizedPrice),
                                 nil ];
        NSLog(@"sent js");

        NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.apply(plugins.inAppPurchaseManager, %@)", successCallback, [callbackArgs JSONSerialize]];
        NSLog(@"js: %@", js);
        [command writeJavascript: js];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONRepresentation` is a category that `SBJson` adds so you have to include `SBJson.h` in the class that uses it.

Comment: That worked!    But I had to download https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads and then copy the contents of the Classes directory to the Xcode classes directory, with "groups" of course.

Comment: The IAP plugin for Phonegap requires it, evidently.

Answer (score 3):

All the stuff to do JSON serialization seems to be already included with the Cordova plugins.
There's no need to download and install yet another JSON library.[(a)](http://codemonger.tumblr.com/post/11098641444/encoding-json-in-objective-c-with-phonegap)

It appears that PhoneGap is in the process of switching from SBJson to JSONKit.[(b)](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/pull/217)

PhoneGap is also in the process of changing all the JSON methods to use a "cdvjk_" prefix. [(c)](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/pull/876)

As far as I can tell, something didn't quite go right during those changes.
What I did was edit the file Plugins/InAppPurchaseManager.m , where I made these changes:

- Add the line

`#import <Cordova/CDVJSON.h>`

- Replace the line

`return [self respondsToSelector:@selector(cdvjk_JSONString)] ? [self cdvjk_JSONString] : [self cdvjk_JSONRepresentation];`

with

`return [self JSONString];`

. (What's the right way to push this or a better bugfix back to the nice PhoneGap people?)

Comment: Awesome, that works! I think you can push that fix back to the repo on Github: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/InAppPurchaseManager